# Laravel - 429 Too Many Requests on 60th Request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

i have a problem. I have an app with aproximately 300 request per minute. I have been deploying my app on GCP with Google Cloud Run.

I have this configuration. Am i making a mistake? because I'm testing it using jmeter app. It could not handle more than 60 requests in lest than 1 minute. It always ended with 429 Too Many requests response.
[image]

I tested my app using JMeter. And it always returning 429 Too Many Requests on 60th request.

Comment: How long does each request take? Are the requests overlapped or sequential? For Google Cloud Run, 429 means the service has reached its maximum number of container instances. Use Stackdriver to review the service logs. There might be more details there. Edit your question with more information and not as a comment.

Comment: Whats the cloud run app about? whats the use case/domain...sounds interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling out to what happend and have a long call with Google customer service, I found the 60th pattern no matter what changes we made on the resource. So, I did another investigation and found that the issue is on laravel.

It's quite hard to find it until I realize that Laravel has a default throtle 60:1, which means 60 requests per 1 minute. So, just need to change that and everything was fine.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. Add information about how to change Laravel, otherwise your answer is just a comment.

Comment: Thank so much for coming back to post this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, 429 means you have hit the container instance limit. Not sure why, as you have 50 connections per container (max). At 60 connections you should have 2 containers

Additionally, if you are in the google sandbox (i.e., free) there are additional limitations placed on your account.

Try the following:

Lower the min instances to 0. Let google automatically figure it out.
Raise the max instances to 200.

Lower the max connections to 25 per container (or raise the ram/cpu to 2).

Let us know.

Comment: Okay thanks. currently im still talking with google support. would send you the updates!

Comment: Hello eric, i have try your proposed solution it still doesn't work. it stays on 60th request. Btw, im using load balancer also, is there any posibility that the problem is in load balancer?

Comment: @Galihlarasprakoso - That is a major detail to be leaving out. Edit your question and include these details.